# CodeIgniter: passing value in the main page using Ajax

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to pass a value in the index() of my controllor called Product.

**Here is the jQuery code:**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $('.call-edit-pdf').on('click',function(){
    var vid = $(this).data('id');

     $.ajax({

type: 'POST',
data:{vid:vid},
url:'<?php echo site_url('product');?>',
success: function(result) {
$('#val-ajax').html(result);
}

 });
   });
     });
```

**This is the product controller**

```
public function index(){

//PASS THE VALUE IN THE RELATED VIEW
$data['c_vid'] = $this->input->post('vid');
$data['modal_edit_pdf'] = $this->load->view('modal/edit-pdf', $data, NULL, TRUE);

....
}
```

Using the scripts above I cannot pass the value in the index() of the product controller. 
I do not know if the jquery url is wrong or not:

```
url:'<?php echo site_url('product');?>'
```

Comment: what value in the index() ?

Answer (score 0):

Your quotes are buggy. Use

```
url:'<?php echo site_url("product");?>',
```

Or

```
url:'<?php echo site_url(\'product\');?>',
```

First should work, try it.